# RoR Server won't detach with -d option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had to reinstall a bunch of my port installs the other day and now when I launch my RoR server with "ruby script/server -d -p 3000" the server wont work.  I am not seeing any errors in the logs.  If I start it with "ruby script/server -p 3000" it works fine.

Any ideas of what I might have uninstalled that would cause this behavior?

Comment: I've asked 4 other questions and none of them were really answered.  I'm not going to accept an bad answer.

Comment: by any chance, are you using Mongrel?

Comment: I did suggest that you use passenger.

Comment: Rodrido I took a while to look through your profile at those 'unanswered questions'.  Perhaps you could be nicer to other people.  It is likely to up your responses.  Nice? -i.e. more thanking , encouragement, etc.  We're humans not robots and yes we do have ego's (actually this site wouldn't run without them!)

Comment: One example "I'm not going to accept a bad answer" - that looks pretty pissy if you really think about it.  How about "Unfortunately none of them really answered my question although I greatly appreciate the answers"?  Your mom might smile then.

Answer (score 1):

I tried upgrading rack and still no luck.

This command worked for me.

```
mongrel_rails start -e production -d
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-d` option runs servers in daemon mode. Mongrel allows for this. Odds are, you uninstalled it.

Comment: I reinstalled mongrel, but that didn't fix.  But its now longer an issue.  Thanks for the help

Comment: May I ask how did you fix this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I hate when people post important technical questions then close them with "I solved it kthxbai."

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in rake 1.1.0 causing this. Try to upgrade to rack 1.3.0. I know this one is not affected.